# Could a Muggle/Squib fool a Wizard/Witch into thinking they had magic using technology?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, muggles

Since most Wizards & Witches do not know much or anything at all about Muggles and Muggle culture would it be possible to fool a Wizard into thinking they were a Witch/Wizard ?

I feel like they could certaintly rig up something using electricty to turn lights on from a distance for instance. Or produce flames using lighters. Even Magicians with slight of hand tricks could work ?

Do you think this would be possible ? Are there any canon instances in lore of something like this happening ?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154426/are-wizards-able-to-tell-magical-people-from-non-magical

Comment: Maybe, if the wizard is dumb enough and the muggle somehow knows how magic works. After all, Mr. Weasley seems to be amazed by technology every time he sees something of it, and he is in the Misuse of Muggle Artifacts department on the Ministry of Magic.

But no, so far no canon instances of this happening as I'm aware. And this question might be opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, however keep in mind that this would be determinate, on the knowledge of the specific witch/wizard, and on the specific Muggle/squib's knowledge of technology, and acces to such. The most advanced spell that could be reliably cast from a tecnology based "wand" would be Lumos (to the best of my knowledge) and perhaps some minor sparks, any advanced magic such as the Patronus charm or even a standard first-year spell such as Wingardium Leviosa, would upon failure expose the Muggle/squib.

Comment: Unless you can provide some source for this, I'm afraid this is all very speculative.

Comment: we know through the text that many wizadrs such as mr. weasley is largely ignorant towards muggles and many of them condescending towards muggles. the wizading world TM sells "wands" that upon pressing a button lights up, i imagine it would be possible to send out sparks, considering we have many different types of lighters, and wincardium leviosa is shown in HPaPS. i dont know what other sources you wish for

Comment: {nods} I guess, from my perspective, a good source would be other something in the canon where a character successfully passes off Muggle technology as magic, or something from Rowling stating that it's possible. Still pretty decent would be citing material from the book and using deductive or inductive reasoning for how Muggle technology could be used to fake magic. I feel like the book has to have had at least one "Muggle technology mistaken for magic" moment, but the best I can think of is Creavey's camera.

Comment: if you want muggle technology to be confused with magic, i think fanfiction would be your best bet, which is at most fanon. however there are several couplings between magic and technology, such as mr weasley's car, bozos(skeeters photographer) camera, the wizarding wireless, sirius blacks mc, and the hogwarts express among others. for another source, i recommend the site wizarding world, which holds many jk writings, one on the subject of technology