# Are Squibs witches/wizards with a disability?

Tags: harry-potter, squib

Now, Squibs are non-magical people born to at least one magical parent. At least one YouTuber compared Squibs not being able to go to Hogwarts to saying "You're in a wheelchair, so you can't go to any school."

So do Squibs have a gene disability (i.e. not having the magical gene, but still seeing Hogwarts)?

Comment: That YouTuber's comparison strikes me incorrect. A more accurate comparison would be "You're in a wheelchair, so you can't go to this specific school where literally every lesson requires that you're able to run."

Comment: Note that in the UK, schools are required to make 'reasonable adjustment' for disability. There's no possible adjustment that could be made to allow a non-magical student to attend a magical school

Comment: @Raditz_35 Disables by wizarding g standards.

Comment: Closely related: [Is there any way to tell a difference between a Squib and a Muggle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103901/is-there-any-way-to-tell-a-difference-between-a-squib-and-a-muggle)

Answer (score 3):

I think rather than disabled, squibs are a class of person we have no real life analog for.  Consider the following points:

1. Disability is normally defined by the ability of the majority of the population. The vast majority of the human population in the Harry Potter universe are muggles, and squibs even possess some abilities that a true muggle lacks, such as the ability to see dementors. In comparison, there are a small number of women in the real world that possess genes for multiple types of cones. They are measurably able to see a wider range of color than the majority of the human population. Yet, the majority isn't considered "partially colorblind." Rather, those women are viewed as uniquely abled compared to everyone else.
2. Within the wizard subpopulation, however, having magic is considered "normal," and squibs and muggles are clearly discriminated against. Muggles, for example, are denied access to magical healthcare unless their condition was illegally caused by wizards. There is also an expectation to have magic if one of your parents was magical. So within the wizarding world, being a squib is seen as a disability, but this perception is only possible due to the rigid class based society of wizard versus muggle, and system of extreme isolation and discrimination that is in place to support these class differences. If the two classes were integrated, squibs would just be a regular person, as is the vast majority of the population.

Comment: Note that Squibs [quite possibly _cannot_ see Dementors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85970/43655), despite Mrs Figg’s claim to the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Squibs have little to no Magical powers but they are born to at least one magical parent,

> Humans with little or no magical talent born into wizarding families
> <sub><sup>*-[Squibs - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/fact-file-creatures/squibs-factfile)*</sup></sub>

They can access the Wizarding World and use a few magical objects.

> Able to access the wizarding world, unlike Muggles, and can use certain magical objects and creatures
> <sub><sup>-[*Squibs - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/fact-file-creatures/squibs-factfile)</sup></sub>

So some squibs do still have Magical powers but very little, but all squibs (even ones without any powers) can see Hogwarts/The Wizarding world.

Comment: i hope this helped, i tried to answer this part: So do Squibs have a gene disability (i.e. not having the magical gene, but still seeing Hogwarts)? instead of the main title