# Is there any way to tell a difference between a Squib and a Muggle?

Tags: harry-potter, squib

If someone has no way to tell who a person's parents are/were (no paperwork), is there a way to tell for a Wizard if someone is a Squib or a Muggle? Or are they 100% functionally equivalent and only different as far as bureaucracy is concerned?

Comment: ... Are you excluding the fact that while 100% of Squibs are aware that the Wizarding world exists, only about 1% or fewer of Muggles are aware of it?

Comment: @Catija 100% might not be true. You could, in theory, have a Squib who was made an orphan at birth, and somehow ended up in a Muggle orphanage. If they never displayed magical ability nobody from Hogwarts would come along to tell them that the Wizarding world existed.

Comment: @Catija - that's not a functional difference. A Muggle can be told about a Wizarding world as easily as a Squib

Comment: Possible dupe of [Is a squib a muggle?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle?s=1|1.5168)

Comment: Sure it is... A muggle uses technology and most wizards are completely unaware of much of the technology around them... which would imply that Squibs are possibly living in a limbo of not having the power of either magic or tech.

Comment: According to JK, muggleborns always have a witch or wizard somewhere on their family tree -- that is, they descend from squibs. So there may be a small genetic difference between muggles and squibs.

Comment: @Richard - the current answers there don't seem to help at all. Accepted one is legalese (explicitly out of scope), and one is about seeing Dementors (which I don't think is provable as opposed to Figg's false statement to Wizangamot to cover for Harry)

Comment: @Catija - again, that's not an innate but learned difference. You can teach a Muggle about magical world and teach a Squib accounting

Comment: @DVK - Yes, I had this one initialy pegged as a dupe but on re-reading, I can see the subtle difference. I suspect it may still attract close votes though.

Comment: You could throw them out a window and see if they bounce down the lane.

Comment: @JohnP - that only distinguishes Neville from a Squib/or/Muggle

Comment: @DVK - Really? Because they did it to Neville in the books, that means it's restricted to only Neville for all of history? Your sense of humor is distinctly lacking this morning.

Comment: @JohnP - full transparency: my response was as ironic as your comment.

Comment: How 'bout making another Quill of Acceptance, one that will write the names of magical children from the age of 0. The actual quill writes their names at the age of 11 to eliminate squibs from the list. So one would have to subtract the *actual* list from the squib-included list, and we'd have a catalogue of all squibs *in Britain*. Surely that'll only work with never generations, but it's been established in canon that the quill (and our new quill too) are fail-proof.

Comment: After reading the comments, considering how much Filch can do, and how muggles can visit Hogsmeade. I wonder if being raised by wizards makes you immune to anti-muggle spells somehow.

Comment: I say bring the person to Hogwarts.

Comment: See here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/189833/89771

Answer (score 15):

You could perform what I'm going to call "the Dementor test". As we learn in *Order of the Phoenix*, Dementors are invisible to Muggles, but *can* be seen by Squibs. If you really needed to, putting them in front of a Dementor and checking if they can see it would be one way to test whether they're a Squib or a plain old Muggle.

Other than that, Squibs seem to be able to see things that Muggles can't. They're not affected by charms and spells intended to disguise objects/locations or repel Muggles, so Argus Filch can see Hogwarts as it really is, rather than as an old ruined castle.

Comment: Is there proof that Dementors can be seen by Squibs? Figg may have just been lying for Dumbledore, no? Good point on Filch, but again it could be that he's specially excluded from prorections as staff? Are there examples of other Squibs?

Comment: @DVK I can't think of any other examples off the top of my head. I'm currently re-reading the books though, so I'll keep an eye out for anything that relates while doing so.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i always wondered if their levels of squibs, aka some who have some magical abilities but its so low that they cant actively use magic, or some who are literally are born as muggles, with 0 magical ability. Its begs the question how/why was filch even hired at hogwarts?

Comment: @DVK: see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85969/4918 Can Squibs see Dementors?

Comment: @Himarm I imagine Filch was unwilling to just leave the magical world behind completely. Most Squibs exclude themselves or are excluded from the world they are born in to, but it's not hard to imagine wanting to stay. As to why he was hired, I imagine there was some element of pity in it.

Comment: @DVK Doesn't matter if they can't see Dementors, use the new and improved Ghost Test to determine the difference between your squibs and muggles! Muggles are unable to see Ghosts whereas Squibs can :).

Comment: From pottermore: "Witches and wizards are much more susceptible to what Muggles call paranormal activity, and will see (and hear) ghosts plainly where a Muggle might only feel that a haunted place is cold or 'creepy'. Muggles who insist that they see ghosts in perfect focus are either a) lying or b) wizards showing off - and in flagrant breach of the International Statute of Secrecy"

Comment: @Simon - if you have a Pottermore quote, definitely worth an answer!

Comment: Second part of the answer is a good one, but JK is on the record saying Squibs cannot see Dementors. http://web.archive.org/web/20110713111531/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=19

Comment: @TenthJustice, doesn't that link just say that Mrs. Figg did NOT see the specific dementors that attacked Harry and Dudley?  Maybe I'm reading incorrectly, but this doesn't seem to make a statement as to whether or not squibs are capable of seeing dementors.

Answer (score 12):

I would rather say - "No" or at least there is not direct test that wizards are aware of and that can distinguish between a muggle and a squib (except for checking their parents).

If we check following dialogue from Harry Potter and The Order of the Phoenix, chapter 8:

> 'I'm a Squib,' said Mrs Figg. 'So you wouldn't have me registered,
>   would you?'
>
> 'A Squib, eh?' said Fudge, eyeing her closely. 'We'll be
>   checking that. You'll leave details of your **parentage with my
>   assistant Weasley.** Incidentally, can Squibs see Dementors?' he added,
>   looking left and right along the bench.

This implies several things:

- Wizards do not have a quick way (like a spell or so) to tell if someone is a squib - Fudge needs to order a background check for it.
- Also most likely there is no a slower test that can confirm this - Fudge does not say "we'll do the squib test later to confirm your statement". Also Dumbledore does not offer to perform such a test so that the authenticity of his witness is proven.
- Wizards have a little knowledge of the skills that squibs possess - Fudge is not sure whether squibs have the ability to see Dementors.

So most probably the wizards don't know a way to determine whether a person is a squib or a muggle. It is possible that such a test exists in the form of a spell or a potion but since wizards don't care much for squibs, they don't care also much to develop them.

Things like being able to see a ghost or a Dementor could serve only as positive confirmation. For example a squib that does not want to be identified as such might just lie that he/she does not see a ghost when asked.

Another possible way would be to directly ask the question and use legimency to check whether the person is telling the truth. Still this also has some issues :

- It is very intrusive so it cannot be used in any situation. Fudge for example did not dare using it of Arabella Figg.
- Very few wizards are adept at it.
- Legimency is not like reading one's mind. The asked person might just ignore the question. In this case the wizard cannot determine whether someone is telling the truth since no answer is given.

Comment: Another version: Fudge was a bigoted bureaucratic useless a**le with very little knowledge of advanced spells :)

Comment: @DVK never underestimate the skills of someone climbing to the hierarchy ladder up to the top and staying there for six years, only to be pushed off by a major crisis. Fudge might have a hidden agenda by refusing to publicly accept that Voldemort is back but he is by no means incompetent.

Comment: possible. Unlikely but possible :)

Answer (score 5):

### You can perform the Moldering Old Ruin Test

When Muggles look at Hogwarts, all that they see is a moldering old ruin.

> “But Hogwarts is hidden,” said Hermione, in surprise. “Everyone knows that . . . well, everyone who’s read Hogwarts, A History, anyway.”
>
> “Just you, then,” said Ron. “So go on — how d’you hide a place like Hogwarts?”
>
> “It’s bewitched,” said Hermione. “If a Muggle looks at it, all they see is a moldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying danger, do not enter, unsafe.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - Chapter Eleven</sub>

However, we see that squibs have no problems entering Hogwarts.

> “He did it, he did it!” Filch spat, his pouchy face purpling. “You saw what he wrote on the wall! He found — in my office — he knows I’m a — I’m a —” Filch’s face worked horribly. “He knows I’m a Squib!” he finished.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* - Chapter Nine ([text legally available online](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/the-chamber-is-opened))</sub>

> Angus got as far as the Sorting Hat before he was exposed. In sheer desperation he threw himself ahead of a girl whose name had been called and placed the Hat upon his head. The horror of the moment when the Hat announced kindly that the boy beneath it was a good-hearted chap, but no wizard, would never be forgotten by those who witnessed it. Angus took off the hat and left the hall with tears streaming down his face.
> <sub>[Scottish Rugby](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby)</sub>

Presumably in order to walk around Hogwarts, they were able to actually see it. Thus squibs can see Hogwarts while muggles cannot. Bring the unidentified person to Hogwarts and ask them what they see.

Comment: Muggles can visit Hogwarts in some circumstances, for example, Moaning Myrtle's parents come to the school after she dies. See *[Do Muggle Parents Visit Their Muggleborn Children at Hogwarts? Are They Totally Excluded?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26734/43164)* So it's not very clear who the muggle-excluding spells affect and don't affect. Maybe it's just that they don't work if you already know about Hogwarts.

Comment: @sumelic - Or maybe they can enter it, but they still won't be able to see it. Filch, however, needs to see it, as he cleans the place.

Comment: Well, I kind of doubt "The dead girl’s parents will be here tomorrow" means that they arrived to what looked to them like a mouldering old ruin, and then stood/walked around in it while people invisibly moved around them. That would be a really odd and probably disturbing experience for them and not something I think you'd want to subject the parents of a recently-dead girl to.

Answer (score 0):

From Pottermore we get this quote on Muggles and their inability to see ghosts:

> Witches and wizards are much more susceptible to what Muggles call paranormal activity, and will see (and hear) ghosts plainly where a Muggle might only feel that a haunted place is cold or 'creepy'. Muggles who insist that they see ghosts in perfect focus are either a) lying or b) wizards showing off - and in flagrant breach of the International Statute of Secrecy.

Now we know that muggles cannot see ghosts but do we know that squibs can?

I think we can take directly from canon that they can definitely see poltergeists, this is evidenced multiple times through Argus Filch and Peeves. I'm fairly certain Filch has interacted with a ghost on at least one occasion, leading me to suggest that you can use a much safer means of testing Squibs and Muggles by using ghosts.

(Unfortunately I don't have my books to hand at the moment)

Comment: JKR was very emphathic that Peeves is not in any way, shape or form a ghost.

Comment: @DVK I know this but unfortunately I cannot scour the books for ghost evidence. I am saying that Peeves is a magical apparition and based on what Muggles can and can't see from the quote I gave it is obvious that a Muggle would not be able to see Peeves. We know filch can definitely see peeves which leads me to believe that he can see ghosts too.

Answer (score -1):

The Harry Potter Wikia has a whole section with the subheading "Differences between Squibs and Muggles." Some might say that is answer enough, but I'll go deeper.

In this section, which can be read in its entirety [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Squib), is the explanation:

> "In addition to being born into magical rather than Muggle families, Squibs are different from Muggles by their knowledge of the wizarding world. They are able to see things that are hidden from the Muggles and have access to certain magical objects and creatures that can help them. Argus Filch, as well as Arabella Figg, have formed wizarding-like relationships with cats."

Others have spoken about their ability to see ghosts and Dementors. Additonally, the relationship between Mr Filch and Mrs Norris is something I had not originally thought of, but I think it is very clear that there is something magical about their relationship and connection. Whenever there is a problem, Mrs Norris seems to come straight to Filch or he comes straight to her. There is a popular rumour that Filch was at least part Kneazle, like Crookshanks, which would make her a magical creature, however this has been denied by JK Rowling on Twitter. I'm not suggesting that Filch really is magical, but perhaps their relationship has grown to that extent because of some residual, non-Muggle magical potential.

I think that the ability to see things a Muggle cannot and special situations like Filch's relationship with his cat serve as evidence that a Squib has magical potential and will likely have had an upbringing that makes them different to a Muggle, who have zero magical sensitivity, potential or ability. Filch obviously thought so too since he ordered his KwikSpell course in an attempt to develop his magical skills. Of course this didn't work, and the KwikSpell company are obviously taking advantage of Squibs, but it seems to me further evidence that there are people who would accept the idea that a Squib certainly has more magic in them than a standard, nothing-to-do-with-the-wizarding-world Muggle.

Comment: If you're going to quote from the/a wiki, you absolutely have to link to it. Should also be using the blockquote formatting. That aside, is any of that information sourced or is it random speculation by whoever wrote that page?

Comment: @Anthony Grist Thank you for the feedback, I'll reformat when I can. Since half of my answer is the same as yours, I wouldn't call it random speculation!

Answer (score -3):

A muggle is a non-magical person. A squib is someone with a magical background but unable to varying degrees able to use it functionally. Other than not being able to cast a proper spell, a squib is indistinguishable from any other witch or wizard.

Comment: Well, that’s rather circular logic. Apart from being able to cast spells and do magic, how exactly are _wizards/witches_ distinguishable from Muggles?