# Why didn't Dumbledore station roosters in the school?

Tags: harry-potter

According to [this answer,](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/162808/85755)

Dumbledore knew that a Basilisk was the source of the petrifactions in the school.

### My simple question

If we take *every fact mentioned* in the series to be true, then the mere crowing of a rooster is fatal to the Basilisk.

> .. And the Basilisk flees only from the **crowing of the rooster, which is fatal to it.**
>    <sub>The Chamber of Secrets</sub>

This was in a library book.

**So why didn't he station hundreds of roosters in the school and see to their protection?**

If a couple of roosters near Hagrid were a threat, surely hundreds in the school would get the job done? Even Riddle would find it hard to eliminate so many of them quicky enough to save the Basilisk.

Hope my question is the first to raise the issue, and not a duplicate!

EDIT: I've taken the quoted quote to mean that the crowing of the rooster has the potential to kill the Basilisk if it doesn't get away quickly enough. Feel free to correct me if my interpretation is wrong!

Comment: I think the premise that Dumbledore knew exactly what he had to deal with is ..very shaky at best. Thus, highly speculative and opinion-based question.

Comment: @Annatar Have you checked the link in my question? It makes a case for the fact that Dumbledore knew that the culprit was the Basilisk. The general consensus, too, seemed to be that. Plus, my previous question on whether Dumbledore didn't know what the monster was got closed.

Comment: @HarryWeasley I did check, and no, there was no real consensus. The comments with the highest votes (except the one from the OP) do disagree with the "Dumbledore-knew" theory.

Comment: @Nahiri Of course it was obvious to the reader. In-universe however, things were a bit different, weren't they? See: The longer answer to OP's last question about the subject (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166648/why-could-no-one-guess-that-a-basilisk-was-the-monster).

Comment: @Annatar (penultimate comment) true, but the most upvoted answer *and* the most upvoted comment support the "Dumbledore knew" theory!

Comment: @HarryWeasley Unfortunately, many people tend to blindly vote for accepted answers.. (and the comment ironically rather points to Dumbledore not suspecting the basilisk) (and that was all that people had to work with, so I don't even blame them for upvoting - the answer is not BAD at all, just one of two concurring theories, and noone posted an answer containing the other one, giving the false impression that there shouldn't be any doubt about this one)

Comment: the linked answer is ...questionable...in my opinion. I don't believe Dumbledore knew what was behind the attacks, but that somehow Vold was involved. He certainly didn't believe Hagrid and Aragog were the culprits, so if he had any idea that there was a basilisk around, I doubt he would have let it ride, as a teacher at the time, and certainly not as headmaster

Answer (score 13):

### He didn't have any Roosters, though Hagrid tried to keep some around

Hagrid had a chicken coop and a number of roosters by his hut. However, over the course of that school year, Ginevra Weasley, under the influence of the Diary Horcrux, snuck into the coop and killed the roosters, one by one, thereby preventing them from being used as a weapon against the Basilisk.

Of course, that's not to say they didn't try to keep the Roosters from being killed.

> “Second one killed this term,” he explained.
>   “It’s either foxes or a Blood-Suckin’ Bugbear, an’ I need the headmaster’s permission ter put a charm around the hen coop.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter & The Chamber Of Secrets - Chapter 11: The Dueling Club*</sub>

But clearly, if any charms *were* put in place, they were easily circumvented by the Voldemort-controlled Ginny, as roosters continued to be killed later on.

> Before Dumbledore could speak another word, however, the
>   door of the office flew open with an almighty bang and Hagrid
>   burst in, a wild look in his eyes, his balaclava perched on top of his
>   shaggy black head and the **dead rooster** still swinging from his
>   hand.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter & The Chamber Of Secrets - Chapter 12: The Polyjuice Potion*</sub>

The fact that the roosters were killed because of the Basilisk was even alluded to when Harry reads from the excerpt Hermione had in her hand.

> “. . . The crowing of the rooster . . . is fatal to it!” he read aloud.
>   “Hagrid’s roosters were killed!
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter & The Chamber Of Secrets - Chapter 16: The Chamber Of Secrets*</sub>

So the answer is, he was possibly planning to, but the roosters were killed.

Comment: -1. D was a teacher of transfiguration. Or i am missing sthg? Mybe you capitalising 'the roosters' means there was a family called 'the Roosters' with abilities to fight Basilisks and Ginny as TR slaughtered all of them?

Comment: Dumbledore was Headmaster during the time of my answer, and I've corrected my grammar.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. What i meant is that Dumbledore was a teacher of transfiguration in the past, therefore transfiguring a few roosters from his beloved lemon drops probably wouldn't have been a big challenge for him.

Comment: Whether or not that would even work is discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162086/can-a-fake-rooster-kill-a-basilisk).

Comment: let's say a 'fake' one wouldn't work (tho i still maintain Draco Malfoy would have made an excellent rooster) but you think it'd have stopped someone like D? If D had wanted roosters, he'd get some, by ordering from Hogsmeade or from any farmhouse

Comment: I think that Dumbledore _had_ roosters, but they were killed. Should he have kept ordering more roosters from around the country until there were no more roosters left? That's a lot of rooster corpses for poor Hagrid to have to clear up.

Comment: could've put some protection charms on them... even made a trap with a rooster bait to catch the culprit who apparently had some mad vendetta against cats and roosters, is all i am saying :-) but he didn't so we'll never know. ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63442/discussion-between-disturbedneo-and-nahiri).

Comment: thanks,  but mybe some other time? Just left work & mounted my bike and it'll be a tad difficult to chat.

Comment: @Nahiri it just means that your entire conversation above was moved to a chatroom. You'll be able to enter the room and chat anytime you like.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Do you mean that the above-mentioned roosters were actually brought to the castle for the purpose of protection? I thought that they were just there for serving the purpose of food!

Comment: Does it especially matter _why_ they were there to begin with? Point is, Dumbledore had access to roosters until they were killed.

Comment: Would it be so hard to procure extra roosters? When the lives of Hogwarts students were in grave danger, I would imagine that Dumbledore wouldn't hesitate to steal roosters from muggle shops if he must. The suggestion that Dumbledore wouldn't deploy roosters because the supply had run out is not strong

Comment: To be realistic, as pointed out by one of the comments in the linked answer, Dumbledore probably decided that deploying roosters wouldn't achieve anything without knowing the basilisk/the chamber's location.It would only make the heir more careful in his operations, making it more difficult to catch him

Answer (score 3):

maybe Dumbledore never figured out the identity of the Slytherin's monster

In the books there is no mention of Dumbledore figuring out that the monster was in fact a Basilisk. 
It is therefore possible that Dumbledore never realised that he should put a hundred roosters in the castle.

Answer (score 0):

One explanation is that Dumbledore simply didn't think of it. I certainly didn't, and wizards are used to getting what they want with spells. They don't have the scientific method, they don't think like muggles, etc. See Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality (fan-fiction).

Another possibility is that Dumbledore wanted Harry to figure it out so he could get closer to defeating Voldemort. This is probably not what he had in mind, but it is possible.