# Is there any evidence that Arabella Figg bred Crookshanks?

Tags: harry-potter

In following links on answers, I came across [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/is-it-ever-revealed-what-crookshanks-is), which says that Crookshanks is a half-Kneazle.

In the HP [wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Kneazle), it's stated that

> Some wizards and witches make a living by breeding Kneazles or part-Kneazles. Arabella Figg, a Squib, makes her living in this manner, which would explain why she has so many cats.

Is there any canon evidence that Figg bred Crookshanks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Unknown (at this time)

There's no evidence to support this hypothesis other than [a quote from JKRs old site](https://web.archive.org/web/20070916044512/http://www.jkrowling.com:80/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=19) that mentions that Arabella Figg made a decent living cross-breeding cat/kneazles for sale.

> Arabella Figg does a roaring trade in cross-bred cats and Kneazles,
>   and if you don‘t know what a Kneazle is yet, shame on you.

It's certainly *possible* that some of these were sold to [Magical Menagerie](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Menagerie) since it appears to be the only magical animal shop in Diagon Alley.